# Evaluating inequality involving powers

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, inequalities

I want to evaluate an inequality of the form $x^a > x$ under the assumptions $x > 1$ and $a > 1$. I expect this inequality to be true, but

```
Simplify[x^a > x, x > 1 && a > 1 && x \[Element] Reals && a \[Element] Reals]
```

returns the inequality as is, and

```
Reduce[{x^a - x >= 0, x > 1 && a > 1}]
```

gives an error ("This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce").

I am not sure what I am missing here and would appreciate any suggestions on how I could evaluate such inequality to be true.

Comment: Since everything is positive (hence real) you can use `Log` on each side of the inequality: `Simplify[Log /@ (x^a > x), x > 1 && a > 1]` which evaluates to `True`

Comment: @BobHanlon I am sure the OP would have no difficulty proving the result, his question is why `Reduce[]` has issues.

Comment: @IgorRivin - I believe that the question was literally "any suggestions on how I could evaluate such inequality to be true" which I interpret as looking for a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Bob's suggestion is indeed useful for me, so I appreciate it greatly! As Igor points out, knowing the underlying cause of this behavior would be also helpful to deal with similar issues if they arise, so I would welcome any further insights.